# jquery to conert object data into string array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am getting data in jquery as below , I want to convert to one dimensional string Array

```
[
    {"2065559857":"2065559482"},
    {"2065559857":"2065553412"},
    {"2065559857":"2065558122"},
    {"2065559857":"7155354848"},
    {"2065559857":"7155577723"},
    {"2065559857":"7153555598"},
    {"2065559857":"2065551189"},
    {"2065559857":"7155544434"},
    {"2065559857":"7296363080"},
    {"2065559857":"7890128703"},
    {"2065559857":"8483894326"},
    {"2065559857":"9077659950"},
    {"2065559857":"9671425573"}
]
```

convert into

```
["2065559482","2065559857","2065553412",.....]
```

Comment: [`var b = a.map(function(a){for(var b in a){return a[b]}});`](http://jsfiddle.net/SNm5T/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` method to turn each object into an array containing the key and value, and then use the same method to concatenate all the arrays:

```
a = $.map(a, function(o){ return $.map(o, function(x, i){ return [x, i]; }); });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/XV7yz/

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
var jsonString = [{"2065559857":"2065559482"},{"2065559857":"2065553412"},{"2065559857":"2065558122"}];    
var myArray = [];

for(var i in jsonString){
    myArray.push([i,jsonString[i]]);
    }
```

Or jQuery:

```
var jsonString = [{"2065559857":"2065559482"},{"2065559857":"2065553412"},{"2065559857":"2065558122"}];   
var myArray = [];

$.each(jsonString, function(key,value){
    myArray.push(value);
    });​
```